# txtとcsvの共通している用語が含まれている配列の個数を求める

Tags: python, python3

1.csvの用語が1.txtの配列の中に含まれている配列の数を求めるプログラムを作成しています.現段階でcountメソッドを用いて1.txtに含まれる用語の個数を出力させました.しかし、用語数では無く、用語が含まれている配列の個数を求めたいのですがcountメソッドと配列のつなげ方が分からなかったので教えて頂きたいです.つまり、以下のような結果になればと考えています.
**2.csv**

```
first,2,1234
second,1,2345
```

**ソースコード**

```
def main():
    # IDと単語のかかれたCSVを１行ずつの配列
    with open('1.csv','r') as a:
        rows = a.readlines()
    a.close()

    # 探す文章をまるごと１つの文字列に入れる
    with open('1.txt','r') as b:
        text=b.read()
        b.close()

    
    id_count = {}

    with open('2.csv','w') as c:
        c.write('用語, 回数, id\n')
        for row in rows:
            # id,word という文字列を , で分割
            tmp = row.split(',')
            id = tmp[0]
            # 改行を取り除くのとcsvの用語を全て小文字にする
            word = tmp[1].strip().lower()
            # textを小文字にし、text に word が何回入ってるか数える
            count = text.lower().count(word)
            #textにもし共通用語がなかったら出力しない
            if count==0:
                pass
            else:
                c.write('%s,%d,%s\n' % (word, count, id))
            
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**1.txt**

```
['I was first.', 'I was first.']
[' I was first.', 'I was second .']
```

**1.csv**

```
1234,first
2345,second
```

Comment: 大文字と小文字は区別しないでカウントするということでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね.txtとcsvのfirstとsecondは最初から小文字だったのでlower()使う必要なかったですね.

Comment: `1.txt` には 2x2 項目あるので, `2.csv` の結果を想定しているなら 行単位の判定 … ということでしょうか？ (カラム単位の判定だと 3行分の結果になるはず, 2x2の 4 項目で扱うと 
first のヒットは 3になるはず なので)。その辺り正確に記したほうがよいかと (行単位の判定, だと)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問者さんの言う「配列」の意味は分かりませんが、1.txtの各行に1.csvの単語（"first"," second"）が含まれているかどうかをチェックして含まれている行数をカウントする、と解釈して2重ループを使った実装にしました。

```
def main():
    # IDと単語のかかれたCSVを１行ずつの配列
    with open('1.csv','r') as a:
        rows = a.readlines()

    # 探す文章をまるごと１つの文字列に入れる
    with open('1.txt','r') as b:
        text=b.read()

    texts = text.split("\n")
    with open('2.csv','w') as c:
        c.write('用語, 回数, id\n')
        for row in rows:
            row = row.strip()
            count = 0
            for t in texts:
                t = t.lower()
                if row.strip().split(",")[1] in t:
                    count = count + 1
            c.write(",".join([row.split(",")[1], str(count), row.split(",")[0]]))
            c.write("\n")
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

ファイル読み込み部分など, 一部変更しています

```py
import csv
import io

with io.StringIO(f1_csv) as fp:
    rows = list(csv.reader(fp))
with io.StringIO(f1_txt) as fp:
    text = fp.read()

lst = text.split('\n')   # [ast.literal_eval(p) for p in text.split('\n')]

with open('2.csv', 'w') as c:
    c.write('用語, 回数, id\n')
    for row in rows:
        cnt = sum(row[1] in v for v in lst)
        if cnt:
            c.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(row[1], cnt, row[0]))

!cat 2.csv
用語, 回数, id
first,2,1234
second,1,2345
```

##### 追記

① `.count` メソッドについて

[テキストシーケンス型 --- str](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) の [文字列メソッド](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

> `str.count(*sub*[, *start*[, *end*]])`
> [*start*, *end*] の範囲に、部分文字列 *sub* が重複せず出現する回数を返します。オプション引数  *start* および *end* はスライス表記と同じように解釈されます。

[シーケンス型 --- list, tuple, range](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

> `s.count(x)`
> `s` 中に `x` が出現する回数

文字列内から部分文字列探索するなら, 質問にあるコードで可能ですが,
リスト内に項目が含まれているかどうかは, 正確に `"['I was first.', 'I was first.']"` のように項目全体示さないとヒットしない。対象の文字列項目が存在すればカウントされます

部分文字列を含む項目をカウントするなら, そのようにコード化が必要

その場合は, `in` 演算子, `find`, `index`, `count` など各種メソッドがあるので適したものを選択する必要があります。また, `re` モジュールなども存在します。

存在するか調べるだけなら `in` 演算子が(たいてい)**最速**

---

② 質問の `1.txt` について

どのように扱いたいのかはっきりしない

- 行単位の文字列のリスト, 2項目
- リスト内のリスト, 4項目の文字列

想定している結果から察すると, 行単位の文字列のリストと思われるが
もしも 4項目, リスト内のリストの構造ならば, コードも変わってきます

```py
import ast
import csv

with open(f1_csv) as fp:
    rows = list(csv.reader(fp))
with open(f1_txt) as fp:
    text = [ast.literal_eval(ln) for ln in fp]

with open('2.csv', 'w') as c:
    c.write('用語, 回数, id\n')
    for row in rows:
        cnt = sum(any(row[1] in item for item in ln)
                                        for ln in text)
        if cnt:
            c.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(row[1], cnt, row[0]))
```